# pyramid + gunicorn_paster development.ini : Error waitress

Tags: pyramid, gunicorn

I am trying to use gunicorn with pyramid.
I installed gunicorn 18 into pyramid 1.5 dedicated virtualenv,
and after activating it, I start gunicorn_paster, but it stops at once with an error :

```
(venv) gunicorn_paster development.ini 

Error: waitress
```

What this error means ?
I tried --debug but it did not give me more clues.
--preload does not work neither.

'pserve development.ini' or mod_wsgi works well, so my virtualenv should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

You need a configuration file.

```
#gunicorn_conf.py
import os

def numCPUs():
    if not hasattr(os, "sysconf"):
        raise RuntimeError("No sysconf detected.")
    return os.sysconf("SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN")

workers = numCPUs() * 2 + 1
bind = "127.0.0.1:8001"
pidfile = "/tmp/gunicorn-app.pid"
backlog = 2048
logfile = "/var/log/gunicorn-app.log"
loglevel = "info"
```

Then launch as shown (note gunicorn_conf.py needs to be in same dir as development.ini)

```
gunicorn --paste development.ini
```

You can leave your development.ini as it is, no need to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I Found the problem : I just had to deactivate/activate again the virtualenv after gunicorn install to have it work.

Answer (score 0):

What server setting does your development.ini have ? By default, it might be using waitress. Kindly check the ini file configuration.
Try this:

```
# ini file
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5000
```